# Load dataset for DeepLearnig model

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, large-data

I'm new in deepLearning and tensorflow. I'm trying to create a neural network with tensorflow and the places365 standard dataset.

I've seen in the tensorFlow's MNIST example that, at the beggining you have to load all the data. That's fine if you have a small dataset but this is not the case. Places365 dataset has 5000 images per class. I'm trying to load only 10 classes but my RAM memory can't handle all of that. This is not necesary since each iteration (epoch) I'm going to use only 128 images.

Isn't it a way to divide the dataset in batches, and load the images just before to train them?

This is some code that I've thought to get the batches supposing that imageTrain is a list of np.arrays where I have loaded all the photos:

```
while(fin != (len(imageTrain)-1)):
    ini = counter*BATCH_SIZE
    fin = (counter + 1)*BATCH_SIZE

    if fin > len(imageTrain):
        fin = len(imageTrain) - 1

    batch_imageTrain = np.reshape(imageTrain[ini:fin],[(fin-ini),256,256,1])
    batch_labelTrain = labelTrain[ini:fin]
    counter = counter + 1
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution. As it says in this link:

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-load-images-efficiently-for-training-a-deep-neural-network-CNNs-My-images-are-too-big-to-load-all-of-them-into-memory

I can save in a list, the name of all the photos, suffle them, and then load only the photos I need for training.
The variable I've mentioned (imageTrain) will be a list of Strings, where each string is the path of each image.

Hope is clear!